# Adding CSS to a foreach loop for an array

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to add a div onto the output of each loop. Without the div the code runs.

```
  foreach($arr as $data){
    echo "<div class=\"rcorners\"> $data['bookID'], $data['saleId']</div>";
  }
```

gives

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.` to concat your string.

```
foreach($arr as $data){
   echo "<div class='rcorners'> " . $data['bookID'] . ",". $data['saleId'] ."</div>";
}
```

Or even

```
echo "<div class=\"rcorners\"> " . $data['bookID'] . ",". $data['saleId'] ."</div>";
```

You can't put Array variables inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's the arrays killing it. Try this:

```
foreach($arr as $data){
echo "<div class='rcorners']> {$data['bookID']}, {$data['saleId']}</div>";
}
```

The curly brackets within the string tell the parser where the variable starts and stops. Without them it doesn't know if you want a $data or $data['bookID'].